# How do i create two or more colums inside a scrollpanel in GWT?

Tags: java, gwt

In general a scroll panel has only one column. If I want two columns, how do I have to modify my code?

```
ScrollPanel scrollPanel =new ScrollPanel(panel1);
scrollPanel.setSize("200px","100px");
DecoratorPanel decoratorPanel =new DecoratorPanel();
decoratorPanel.add(scrollPanel);
RootPanel.get("gwtContainer").add(panel);
RootPanel.get("gwtContainer").add(decoratorPanel);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can scroll a Grid, FlexTable or LayoutPanel so you will have a common scroll for a flexible layout.

```
LayoutPanel lp = new LayoutPanel();
lp.add(whatever1);
lp.add(whatever2);

lp.setWidgetLeftWidth(whatever1, 0, Unit.PCT, 50, Unit.PCT);
lp.setWidgetRightWidth(whatever2, 0, Unit.PCT, 50, Unit.PCT);

ScrollPanel scrollPanel = new ScrollPanel(lp);
scrollPanel.setSize("200px", "100px");

DecoratorPanel decoratorPanel = new DecoratorPanel();
decoratorPanel.add(scrollPanel);

RootPanel.get("gwtContainer").add(decoratorPanel);
```

Hope it helps